# How to pause delivery of queued messages from broker.xml

Tags: activemq-artemis

Using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.29.0

I want to pause/resume the delivery of queued messages from `broker.xml`. In the [Model Documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html) I found configurations only to enable and disable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pause or resume a queue using `broker.xml`. You can only use the management operations `pause()` and `resume()` respectively on the corresponding [`QueueControl`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html). You can invoke management operations in a number of ways, e.g.:

- A browser via the web console
- A GUI JMX tool like [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/management/using-jconsole.html) or [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) with the [MBeans Browser](https://visualvm.github.io/plugins.html) plugin
- A Java program using the JMX API
- An HTTP utility like `curl`
- etc.

You can find more information in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html).